# Linux accessing a Windows server proxy.pac script

Tags: browser, http-proxy

I'm using a Slackware 14 VirtualBox guest on Windows 7 behind a work proxy. Having battled a bit with network settings I've gotten to the point where I can browse the web in Firefox by using the proxy.pac script URL in LAN settings.

My question is how can I set up commandline packages (slackpkg and R in particular) which require the physical proxy address rather than using URL to download content. I can't figure out what the proxy address is that I should update /etc/profile with.

What am I missing here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If firefox uses the desired proxy, then you can get the Proxy's IP and port. As root:

```
netstat -t -n -p | grep firefox
```

Comment: works perfectly - simple answer and easy to implement in a script. thanks